# Jekyll on Github Pages: how to include external content inside footnotes?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

As Jekyll-Scholar is not available on Github Pages, I am trying to find a workaround to have some kind of bibliography features, using kramdown footnotes and include. I would like to stay in the Github Pages workflow and not to compile the website locally.

I have a collection with all references in `_data/biblio.yaml`:

```
- authors: Me, Her and Him
  title: A Serious Article
  key: ref1
```

In `page1.md` I have:

```
This is a sentence with a citation[^1]

[^1]: 
    {% include citation.html key="ref1" %}
```

And in `_includes/citation.html` I have a template for citations:

```
{% assign citation = site.data.biblio | where:"key", include.key | first %}
<span class="cit-authors">{{citation.authors}}</span>, <span class="cit-title">{{citation.title}}</span>
```

This does not work, as after compilation the citation is rendered *before* and not *inside* the footnote definition:

```
<p>
<span class="cit-authors">Me, Her and Him</span>, <span class="cit-title">A Serious Article</span>
</p>

<div class="footnotes">
  <ol>
    <li id="fn:1">
      <p><a href="#fnref:1" class="reversefootnote">&#8617;</a></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

The desired result is obviously to have the included content inside the `<li>` block.

Is there a reason why this does not work? Is there any way to make it work as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `_includes/citation.html`, your assign statement introduces a useless line break, which breaks kramdown parsing.

You can remove the line break between assign and html

```
{% assign citation = site.data.biblio | where:"key", include.key | first %}<span class="cit-authors">{{citation.authors}}</span>, <span class="cit-title">{{citation.title}}</span>
```

**or** use the new liquid [whitespace control](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/) (`{%- tag -%}`)

```
{%- assign citation = site.data.biblio | where:"key", include.key | first -%}
<span class="cit-authors">{{citation.authors}}</span>, <span class="cit-title">{{citation.title}}</span>
```

Comment: I implemented your second solution, worked like a charm! Thank you very much